# How can I execute a SQL Server overloaded stored procedure with firedac

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, firedac

This my code : 
but at run time always raises an error : 
'[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure ''BPM_HIS_DB.dbo.MSP_Banks;4''
or some like this

```
LFDSP:=TFDStoredProc.Create(nil);
try
 With LFDSP do
  begin
   Connection:=FDConnection1;
   FetchOptions.Items := LFDSP.FetchOptions.Items - [fiMeta];
   Overload:=4 ;
   StoredProcName := 'MSP_Banks;4';
   Prepare;
   Params.ParamByName('BankId').Value := 1;
   Open();
 end;
finally
 LFDSP.Free;
end;
```

Comment: You're calling `Prepare` before defining the parameters.  You have to define your parameters before doing this.  See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34656034/327083

Comment: Thank you
But still did not answer
I do not have a single problem with enforcement procedures
My problem in SQL Server overload.
With this method you first run the procedure I was
In fact, do not overload
A package Name for Oracle database is initialized
But for banks SQL Server
Methods It should be the other way
If you run SQL on your example did you hold with overload and thus send a


Thank

Comment: For Example   This Procedure Link: http://s6.picofile.com/d/0b8d7e56-2d92-4ee4-8d88-0d678d3abd0f/Msp_Bank.sql   I'm procedure 2 or 3 or 4 or ... I run